# Splitting up results of knockout data into 2 columns

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

Was curious if there was an easy way to split up the following code into 2 columns via Knockout and HTML. I know how to do it in the CSS but really it's just to split results 1-5 and 6-9. Here's my code. Screenshot attached as well. Thank you[image: Results]

```
         <div class="item summary">
              <h3> <?=l(479)?> </h3>
                <div data-bind="foreach:$data.summary">
                  <div>
                   <span data-bind="text:$data.sequence + '.'"></span>
                    <span data-bind="text:$data.label + ':'"></span>
                    <span data-bind="text:$data.value"></span>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the length isn't going to change you can duplicate the markup for each block and add a `slice()`. It's not the most elegant but it's probably the easiest.

```
<!-- ko if: summary && summary.length > 0 -->
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data.summary.slice(0,5)">
        ...
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data.summary.slice(5)">
        ...
<!-- /ko -->
```

If you want something a little more dynamic you can create a computed function that splits your array into multiple pieces and use a nested foreach instead:

```js
function viewModel(){
    var self = this;
    this.summary = [
      new Summary(1),
      new Summary(2),
      new Summary(3),
      new Summary(4),
      new Summary(5),
    ];
    
    this.summaryBlocks = ko.computed(function(){
      if(self.summary && self.summary.length > 0){
      var size = self.summary.length / 2;
        return [
          self.summary.slice(0,size), 
          self.summary.slice(size)
        ];
      }else{
        return [];
      }
    });
}

function Summary(val){
    this.sequence = 'sequence';
    this.label = 'label';
    this.value = val;    
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="item summary">
  <h3> <?=l(479)?> </h3>
  <div data-bind="foreach: summaryBlocks">
    <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;" data-bind="foreach:$data">
      <div>
        <span data-bind="text:$data.sequence + '.'"></span>
        <span data-bind="text:$data.label + ':'"></span>
        <span data-bind="text:$data.value"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: Another snippet for dealing with a variable number of columns

```js
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;

  this.columns = ko.observable(1);
  this.summary = [new Summary(1), new Summary(2), new Summary(3), new Summary(4), new Summary(5), new Summary(6), new Summary(7), new Summary(8), new Summary(9)];

  this.summaryBlocks = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < self.columns(); i++) result.push([]);

    if (self.summary && self.summary.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < self.summary.length; i++) {
        var col = i % self.columns();
        result[col].push(self.summary[i]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  });
}

function Summary(val) {
  this.sequence = 'sequence';
  this.label = 'label';
  this.value = val;
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

columns: <span data-bind="text: columns"></span>
<br/><input type="range" min=1 max=5 data-bind="value: columns" />

<div class="item summary">
  <div data-bind="foreach: summaryBlocks">
    <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;" data-bind="foreach:$data">
      <div style="border: 1px dashed blue;">
        <span data-bind="text:'item ' + value"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's awesome! One question though, it seems to be bombing out if the data comes back null. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Sure. If you're using the first version you can wrap everything in an `if` or `with` binding to make sure the array contains elements. For the second version you could add that logic to the computed function instead. I'll update my answer

Comment: thanks @jason spake - but I'm getting this error :(. Summary isn't a function but i tried changing that too.

Comment: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return order().items.length > 0 }"
Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return order().items }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return $data.summary.length > 0 }"

Comment: Is Summary an observable in your model? I assumed it was, but if it's just a flat js object you'll need to remove the parenthesis after it in the computed function. (`summary().blah` -> `summary.blah`)

Comment: i actually got it to work like this.   <div data-bind="if:$data.summary">